# How to get the ratelimited person in `commands.Bucket` in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I have an AntiSpam system in place, which is made in `on_message` event of discord.py. The code to the same is below -->

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    bucket = bot.AntiSpam.get_bucket(message)
    retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
    if retry_after:
        print('Someone was being naughty')
        await message.channel.purge(before=datetime.utcnow(), after=datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(seconds=5))
        await message.channel.send(f'Please don\'t spam, {message.author.mention}', delete_after=5.0)
```

This deletes **every** single message sent since the last 5 seconds. How to make it so that it would **only** delete the message sent by that spammer? I know I have to use the `check` kwarg of `TextChannel.purge()`, but I need a way to make the check. Can I get any help regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check would be very simple:

```py
def check(m):
    return m.author == message.author

await message.channel.purge(before=datetime.utcnow(), after=datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(seconds=5), check=check)
```

We're checking if the author of the message passed into the check is the same as the author of the previous message.